# React hooks not setting asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, electron

I am fetching a bunch of data on initial render of the page. Whenever I goto set the data using useState from react it takes around 2500-3200ms to set.  Which is fine, however it seems to run sync not async. Causing it to lockup the thread. I was wondering if anyone knew why. I am using Electron, and ipcRenderer to fetch the data from the server.

```js
  const [mods, setMods] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.invoke('fetchMods', '').then(res => {
      console.time('invokeMods');
      setMods(res);
      setLoading(false);
      console.timeEnd('invokeMods');
    });

    return () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('fetchMods');
    };
  }, []);
```

Output:

```
invokeMods: 2794.64404296875 ms
invokeMods: 2807.699951171875 ms
```

Comment: It's probably better to think of setMods as a synchronous function which sets up a new render, which is asynchronous. What it `res`? If it is an entire http response object it could be HUGE.

Comment: I see now it's an ipc message so it's probably not that the size of the object is creating the problem.